# Angular 4 Highcharts - needs to put margin between items

Tags: angular, highcharts

I working with HighCharts package in angular 4 project and I'm using bar chart but I don't know how to make space between each bar chart

Here is the result:
[image]

Here is what I want is the add margin or space between each line like red line in this pic:
[image]

Here is my chart options :

```
this.opt_chart = {
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      tooltip: self.toolTipFormatter(),
      xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        visible: false,

        labels: {
          useHTML: true,//Set to true
          formatter: function () {//use formatter to break word.
            return '<div style="width:' + this.labelWidth + 'px">' + this.value + '</div>';
          },
          enabled: true,
          align: 'right',
          style: this.getXAxisStyle()
        }
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          animation: {
            duration: 1000
          },
          point: {
            events: {
              click: function () {
                let obj = this.category;
                self.lineClicked(obj);
              }
            }
          },
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            format: '{y} €/hab',
            align: 'center',
            enabled: false,
            style: {
              color: 'black',
              fontSize: '15px'
            }
          },
          minPointLength: 3
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        visible: false,

        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          align: 'right',
          formatter: function () {
            return self.utils.clean(this.total, ' €/hab');
          }
        },
        plotLines: [{
          color: '#4d4d4d',
          width: 10,
          height: 100,
          value: 0,
          zIndex: 10
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        reversed: false,
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Intérêts',
        pointWidth: this.lineHeight,
        stack: '',
        color: this.bleuNuit,
        borderRadius: 7
      }],

      credits: {
        enabled: false
      }
    };
```

I hope I made my idea clear, waiting for your help and thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve, it looks like the chart is already spaced like the red line? Regardless, to change margin/padding between points, use: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.pointPadding

Comment: @ewolden Hey, I want to add more space between lines because I need it in another feature, I tried pointPadding property but did not work

Comment: Well, seeing as you have not given any data with your config example, I can't do much more to help you. Including a subset of your data and mentioning what kind of feature you need to add would be helpful. Have a read on how to create a [mcve]

Comment: @Younes are you sure you use `bar` chart? From your chart options it looks more like a `line` series. If this is a line series, then use `lineWidth`. If this is a `bar` series, then simply decrease `pointWidth` in your code: `pointWidth: this.lineHeight,`.